# Fetching Product Options/Attributes on Product Listing Page

Tags: bigcommerce

On this page https://stencil.bigcommerce.com/docs/product-resources BigCommerce has mentioned that Product Object has "Options" but in the theme, I am not able to retrieve anything from options property. I am trying to access this in Category Page.

I want to do above because I have to add product attributes on product listing page "templates\components\products\card.html". I need this here because I have to remove quick view option and directly put the product option under product title on this page. Over here I am able to get product's id, name, sku etc but not getting any properties from product options.

I have already asked to BigCommerce Support team and they don't have any solutions and referred me to check here.

Answer (score 0):

The category page calls the common product card model, which does not include the product options property:

https://stencil.bigcommerce.com/docs/common-product-card-model

To get product option data on the category page, you'll need to call the API. One lightweight solution for handling this is to use AWS Lambda with Amazon API Gateway. API Gateway defines an endpoint URL that you can use to trigger a Lambda function that runs a request to the BigCommerce API for product data.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-on-demand-https.html